# Limiting G Suite Domain-wide Delegation for a service account

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm working on an enterprise application that will be granted authority to access email data by the domain administrator. I've enabled Domain-wide Delegation for the app. But based on feedback from customers, I would like to be able to limit the access my app has to specific groups in the domain, e.g. Finance. This will allow the domain admin to give email access to our app for just those users in the company that will actually use the product.

Is there any way to restrict an app that has been granted Domain-wide Delegation to  one or more specific groups or organizational units in the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Google Organisation Units then you can limit that way.  A Finance Organisation Unit would be granted access to the Application.